# Row Bootstrap Responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a simple bootstrap code

```
<div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            one

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            two

        </div>
```

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">

            three

        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">

            four

        </div>

</div>
```

in this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZcy8.jpg)

situation responsive 1 (normal)

I want instead the situation 2 !

Solutions?

Thanks

Comment: You can divide your layout in 2 columns instead of rows where each column will have 2 rows.

Answer (score 4):

You need to make 2 outer columns and nest inner colums like this..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    one
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    three
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    two
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    four
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/EP61f111NO

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is stack the `rows` in a `.col-md-*` to create two cols for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <!-- Left col -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Col 1</h1>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Col 1</h1>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Col 1</h1>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Right col -->
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Col 1</h1>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Col 1</h1>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Col 1</h1>
                <p>Description</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```